# Navegar por telas levando informação

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou trabalhando com AngularJs e Ionic, criando uma aplicação móvel. Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de navegar entre as telas levando informações de uma tela para outra. Por exemplo:
Em uma tela de cadastro eu quero ir para tela de produto e voltar com o produto selecionado, depois ir para tela de vendedor e voltar novamente para tela de cadastro agora com vendedor e produto.
No momento eu mando a informação pelo URL, exemplo: `incluir/1/1` - cada número representa um código que eu posso buscar no banco mais tarde.
Outra forma é usar o `windows.localstorage['vendedor']` que armazena na memoria do aparelho.
Existe uma forma mais pratica? Compartilhem, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe também outro meio de enviar uma informação de uma tela para outra que é guardando um objeto no escopo da aplicação ($rootScope).

Exemplo:

```
$rootScope.venda = {
   cliente: 1,
   produto: 1
};
```

Comment: Realmente funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: Imagina haha! :)

Answer (score 3):

Não é recomendável o uso de `$rootScope` para fazer o que você busca. Os serviços (`service` e `factory`) do `AngularJs` estão ai para isso.

#### Por que não usar o $rootScope?

`$rootScope`, como o nome já diz, é um scopo de raiz, comum e acessível em todos os `controller` que você possui. Se você cria um `$rootScope` com o nome vendas: `$rootScope.vendas` ele será acessível em todos os `controller`, podendo ser alterado, deletado e/ou inserido um novo valor.

Trabalhando com aplicações curtas e simples, não há problema. Mas quando você começa a trabalhar com diversos `controller` que precisam desse dado, eventualmente você pode criar um `$scope` que não tenha nada a ver com o `$rootScope` mas que modifique aquele valor. Ou que você acabe perdendo controle de qual função está modificando aquele `$rootScope`.

Outro ponto, se o usuário deixar a aplicação e voltar mais tarde, ele vai conseguir continuar de onde parou? Utilizando os mesmos dados armazenados anteriormente? Ou o `$rootScope` vai ser resetado ao seu estado inicial?

Obs.: Mais importante, não caia na tentação de criar uma função usando `$rootScope`.

#### Quando usar o $rootScope?

É mais recomendável utilizar o `$rootScope` apenas para definições globais que não sofram alterações. Ex.: Nome da aplicação, nome do usuário logado em mensagem de boas vindas (Ainda há de se analisar essa), enfim. Dados que você não vá modificar (ou pelo menos não com tanta frequência).

#### O que utilizar?

Como você já comentou que está utilizando `localStorage`, recomendo que você se mantenha com ele. O seu controle vai ser muito melhor sobre os dados que você precisa/manipula, além de poder reutilizar os dados, caso o usuário saia da aplicação e volte mais tarde. Ainda pode definir um prazo de expiração para aquela informação.

Obs.: Ainda mantém a `url` limpa, sem um monte de dados.

---

#### Observações

Logicamente tudo isso deve ser levado em consideração analisando o tamanho/complexidade de sua aplicação vs reais melhorias/otimizações que você vai ter.

O uso de `$rootScope` realmente deve ser evitado, mas nem sempre é viável criar todo esse cenário para manipular os dados se for algo simples.

Answer (score 1):

A prática mais comum é o uso de query parameters, no caso exatamente como você está utilizando. Assim, ao carregar um controlador, é mais simples de saber se a rota em questão é para edição ou novo registro.

Answer (score 1):

Não recomendo utilizar o Jquery com o Ionic: a filosofia do jquery é de manipular o DOM diretamente, o que vai contra a filosofia do angularjs que manipula o DOM através de diretivas. Há também uma questão de performance.

Você pode guardar objetos no $rootScope, no entanto, é melhor modelar seus dados de forma que sejam fornecidos por uma `factory`.

Factories são singletons, isto é, definidas e inicializadas uma única vez.

Por exemplo, vc pode definir uma `factory` UserSession onde você armazena todas as variáveis relacionadas ao usuário naquela sessão: produto-corrente, carrinho-de-compras, etc. e acessá-la de qualquer controller na app.